# Where can I find list of the available Joomla-WYSIWYG-Editor buttons etc

Tags: development, editor, xml, form

I'm currently developing a component and I'm using a form. I'd like to give the user a limited access to the functionality of the editor.

According to http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type I can limit the functionality with the help of the parameter "hide" like this:

> hide (optional) array of plugin buttons to be hidden. eg... set
>   buttons="true" hide="readmore,pagebreak"

This works perfectly fine for those two mentioned buttons, but where can i find a list of all the editor buttons? (Marked ones in the following image)

[image]

My form-xml looks like this:

```
<field
        name="editorField"
        type="editor"
        description="COM_HELLOWORLD_FORM_EDITOR"
        label="COM_HELLOWORLD_FORM_EDITOR_LABEL"
        required="true"
        hide="readmore,pagebreak"
        size="20" 
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These buttons are coming from the editors XTD plugins. The defaults XTD buttons are article, pagebreak, readmore, image. But there are extensions that can install their own XTD buttons, e.g Joomla Works Simple Image Gallery Pro, or NoNumber Content Templater etc..

Check in the plugin manager for the Editor's plugin to see what's there.

But I think I misunderstood your question, and you have misunderstood what the hide parameter does and what is meant with the plugin buttons for the editor form field.

I think you can't control the Tiny MCE features from the XML. There are some settings that allow a level of control if you go to edit the tinyMCE plugin, through the plugin manager.

I would suggest to use another editor like JCE and create your desired profiles to assign it for each use-case.

Comment: Thanks! I know JCE from a diffrent project, i did not expect that the default editor is so limited.
In the plugin config i can find an option "functionality" with the values "Simple", "Advanced" and "Extended". Can I configure those values in the XML?

Answer (score 5):

Every folder inside the following folder is a plugin for Tiny-MCE editor:

```
/media/editors/tinymce/plugins/
```

They are:

```
advlist
anchor
autolink
autoresize
autosave
bbcode
charmap
code
colorpicker
compat3x
contextmenu
directionality
emoticons
example
example_dependency
fullpage
fullscreen
hr
image
importcss
insertdatetime
layer
legacyoutput
link
lists
media
nonbreaking
noneditable
pagebreak
paste
preview
print
save
searchreplace
spellchecker
tabfocus
table
template
textcolor
textpattern
visualblocks
visualchars
wordcount
```

Comment: You are right of course ;-) Very objective answer though. I can't limit the features of the TINY MCE with this "hide" field.

Comment: With `hide` attribute, you can only remove editors-xtd buttons. I tried to remove other buttons like `hr` via javascript, but it's not possible to do this after initialization. So, you can remove the tinyMCE instance and then initialize with new `plugins`, `toolbar1`, `toolbar2` etc.